# Accesing Private Methods in java?

Tags: java, methods, private, overriding

how to implement such a functionality to access private members ?

Java checks access permissions during compilation only. Are you surprised? I was surprised very much to find out this fact.

So you can create skeleton of the third party class (even with empty implementations.). The interesting method should be protected instead of private. Now write your subclass and compile it against your stub. Then package only your subclass and try to run it with the "real" class. It should work.
I have tried it when I had to access private method or field and it worked fine for me.

ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440051/1312423

Comment: Where is the interrogation mark ? Is there a question ?

Comment: Did you just ask something I missed??

Comment: FLAGGED.. and by the way #ME #notsurprised.

Comment: And you can use reflection and invoke the settings. Big Surprise. And you can compile a JVM that just ignores it. In essence, don't trust the computers that you don't control. All of us already knew.

Comment: there is a link to the answer provided for question "HOW TO OVERRIDE PRIVATE METHODS ?" want to know how to implement such a functionality.

Comment: i can invoke private method but i want to get it done through this way.

Comment: rather than emphasizing on what is written there please try to get what am i asking. i want to invoke private method through that way which is already written there... and some body already closed it.

Comment: You can see the *five* people who voted to close the question. The problem is what you are trying to do a) doesn't sound useful b) can't be done AFAIK.

Comment: ok i am trying to ask same question again but in a efferent way and let's see does it make any difference.

Comment: @TheVOYOU quoting from what your link pointed to:  
> I have not tried this trick with inheritance but I have tried it when I had to access private method or field and it worked fine for me.  
I would try using reflection: get the method from the class, set its accessibility modifier, call `myMethod.invoke(attributes)`  

However, I would never ever even think on considering this as a solution I would recommend to anyone, who I don't want to kill me in the future. This is evil (if it works at all - I have no evidence of this, and I won't soil my hands and brain with this kind of abuse)

Comment: @ppeterka first of all thanks to understand the problem; thanks for the solution

Answer (score 3):

> Java checks access permissions during compilation only. Are you surprised?

Yes, because it checks the access modifier at runtime as well.

---

I start with

```
public class AnotherClass {
    protected static void printMe() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        AnotherClass.printMe();
    }
}
```

and it compiles and runs.

If I change the `printMe()` to be `private` without re-compiling `Main` it does compile but when I run `Main` I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method AnotherClass.printMe()V from class Main
    at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Comment: you can't even compile it if you change access specifier from protected to private...

Comment: You can compile `AnotherClass` without re-compiling `Main`

Comment: what the point with that you can always compile any class with private method.

Comment: Compile a class by itself and you can make just about everything private.

Comment: thank you but i can't mark your answer as accepted if you could answers please see what am i asking although it's already closed.

Comment: The answer is; you can't do it. I have demonstrated what happens when you try.

Comment: this is not what http://stackoverflow.com/a/4440051/1312423 is trying to say.

Comment: I suggest you add a comment asking what he meant.

Comment: thanks i am trying to find out by myself and thanks for your consideration and support.

Comment: The only think I can think of is something to do with nested classes, but AFAIK its only the compiler which allows access of private members of other classes in the same outer class and javac has to generate accessor methods in the byte code as the JVM doesn't allow this.